# How to create a parameterized STORED PROCEDURE with CRUD operation in MYSQL Version(6.0.11-alpha-community)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I created a parameterized STORED PROCEDURE with CRUD operation in  MYSQL Version(6.0.11-alpha-community)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `mae`.`USP_CustomersToken_CURD`(IN CID INT , IN CName VARCHAR(50), IN CToken VARCHAR(250), IN CTokenTime DATETIME , IN OPType INT)

 BEGIN

IF (OPType = 1) --Insert
THEN
INSERT INTO tbl_CustomersTokenInfo (ID, CustomerName, Token, TokenTime) VALUES (CID, CName, CToken, CTokenTime)

ELSEIF (OPType = 2) --delete
THEN
DELETE FROM tbl_CustomersTokenInfo WHERE ID = CID

ELSEIF (OPType = 3) --Update
THEN
UPDATE tbl_CustomersTokenInfo SET CustomerName = CName, Token = CToken , TokenTime = CTokenTime WHERE ID = CID

ELSEIF (OPType = 4) --Select
THEN
SELECT * FROM tbl_CustomersTokenInfo WHERE ID =CID

ELSEIF (OPType = 5)--Fetch 
THEN
SELECT * FROM tbl_CustomersTokenInfo
END IF

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but when I executing this SP I'm getting this below error :

Query: CREATE PROCEDURE `mae`.`USP_CustomersToken_CURD`(IN CID INT , IN CName VARCHAR(50), IN CToken VARCHAR(250), IN CTokenTime DATETI...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN
INSERT INTO tbl_CustomersTokenInfo (ID, CustomerName, Token, TokenTime) VAL' at line 4

### Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec

I'm new to MYSQL commands and syntaxes if I did any mistake give the best approach .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. MySQL (unlike most other DBMS) doesn't like comments introduced with `--` where no space follows `--`.
2. You need to terminate all the statements, including the `IF` statement (after `END IF`), with a `;`.

Correct that:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `mae`.`USP_CustomersToken_CURD`(IN CID INT , IN CName VARCHAR(50), IN CToken VARCHAR(250), IN CTokenTime DATETIME , IN OPType INT)

 BEGIN

IF (OPType = 1) -- Insert
THEN
INSERT INTO tbl_CustomersTokenInfo (ID, CustomerName, Token, TokenTime) VALUES (CID, CName, CToken, CTokenTime);

ELSEIF (OPType = 2) -- delete
THEN
DELETE FROM tbl_CustomersTokenInfo WHERE ID = CID;

ELSEIF (OPType = 3) -- Update
THEN
UPDATE tbl_CustomersTokenInfo SET CustomerName = CName, Token = CToken , TokenTime = CTokenTime WHERE ID = CID;

ELSEIF (OPType = 4) -- Select
THEN
SELECT * FROM tbl_CustomersTokenInfo WHERE ID =CID;

ELSEIF (OPType = 5)-- Fetch 
THEN
SELECT * FROM tbl_CustomersTokenInfo;
END IF;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```